# Why are ultrasound machines so big?

Tags: ultrasound

Ultrasound machines tend to be pretty bulky. Even the portable ones often are hefty items that look like those old Compaq portable computers from 1985.

Very recently there are some smaller ones like the Nanomaxx, but by and large they are still usually bulky machines. The smaller ones tend to have signified reduced beam resolution.

Do these machines require some special kind of electronics or large power supplies that make the machines so big, or is it just a case of medical technology being behind the curve and using outmoded computers from yesteryear?

Comment: I'd say there's no requirements for them to fit in the pocket. You still need a bed for the patient to lay down, what harm is there in having a laptop-sized unit next to it?

Comment: what is your reference point?  what is on the market (there are large and small) or what is in use?.  if a piece of equipment works why waste money replacing it for the latest and greatest. Equipment is replace if it is broken, no longer fit for purpose & sometimes because the depreciation period has expired justifying a capital investment (£10 or £100k)

Comment: Being a engineer working on ultrasound machines, I'd love to answer this but since this question is closed, here's a comment:
[1] high end computing h/w (dual proc+workstation mobo in some cases) to support all the advanced features
[2] dedicated boards for multi transducer connectors, pulsar, adc, beamforming, power regulation, h/w video capture etc
[3] power supply + batteries 
[4] mechanically stable, ergonomic design to handle the multiple displays/touchscreens with 
[5] ventilation for all the heat generated inside (the system needs to work in a variety of environments)
and more ...

Answer (score 2):

Beam resolution on an ultrasound is PURELY a function of the transducer, not the size of the box.

Your assumption, though, is simply wrong.  There are small ultrasounds, plenty of them.  The way the machines have been traditionally used, though, did not demand small size, and a big, self-contained machined complete with display fit into the clinical model just fine.  Now that such things are becoming field-deployed, they are becoming much smaller.

The fact that much of the old technology is still around, and companies are slow to update to more modern designs is almost certainly due to the regulatory environment.  You can't just change a medical device.  The generic pulsed echo ultrasound system is a [Class II FDA device](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?fr=892.1560), approved through the 510K mechanism.  You can see guidance documents for bringing such a system through the FDA process [HERE](http://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/DeviceRegulationandGuidance/GuidanceDocuments/ucm070856.htm)

Changing an approved device means redealing with the FDA, sending in 510K modifications, subjecting yourself to re-review in some cases, etc.  There is a lot of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" type thinking in the medical device regulatory arena.

The device you chose is not in the FDA system, as it is a veterinary product (otherwise, I'd be telling you the date of the FDA approval to market), but they have their own regs.  For that example, you're probably just talking about the business model vs the cost of opening up a design cycle.  If they have no concerns about losing market share, the product will stay the same.  Though, the same company sells [laptop sized systems](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/animals-ultrsound-doppler-10-Careshine-VET_60525451486.html).

Comment: If what you say is true (bulky is only found in clinical settings), then there would be no reason to have bulky portable ultrasounds, but there are. For example, look at the Careshine vet ultrasound (https://www.amazon.com/Careshine-Veterinary-Pregnancy-Digital-Ultrasound/dp/B012307ESU/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1484746629&sr=8-11&keywords=ultrasound+machine). If it is so easy to make portable ultrasounds, then why is this portable ultrasound so bulky?

Comment: @TylerDurden  -- I edited to include more info.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if there are two competing devices at roughly the same price, the more "bulky" one instinctively looks like more value per money to a clueless customer – and in a clinical administration vs. clinical staff vs. engineer settings, by god, the clues are distributed very unevenly.

Comment: Big devices are also harder to steal or misplace in a busy hospital environment.  They may be easier for engineering staff to service.  "Small" doesn't always meet the needs.

Comment: Patients come into it, too.  "Why am I paying hundreds of dollars so you can test me with a toy?"

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on this question, it does appear that there is no specific technological barrier to small, cheap ultrasound machines. The reason why many machines are bulky appears to be purely a side effect of the regulatory and market environment.

For example, there are handheld ultrasounds now that plug into any pocket computer which have part costs of $200 to $300 but which retail for $6000 or more, and this appears due solely to the restricted market environment. [So for example, in India](http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2007/feb/28/20070228-113751-7882r/):

> Under Indian law, doctors operating ultrasound machines must fill out
>   forms showing the reason for each procedure, which is permitted only
>   in the case of an abnormal pregnancy. But the government can only
>   monitor the 25,770 machines that have been officially registered.

So, we can see that ultrasounds are very strictly regulated not just in the US, but all around the world, as in the case of India quoted above where doctors have to specially register each and every machine and must fill out a form and submit it to the government each and every time they use the machine.

These restrictions apparently cause manufacturers to use technology that is constantly 10 years out of date and so many machines are being made even today with cathode ray terminal displays that became obsolete in computers 15 years ago.

Comment: The regulatory environment, and not just competitive pricing and restricted market, also enters into the cost calculation.  If you spend a year developing something, and a year gathering validation data, and 9 months in the regulatory process while your patent is timing out, you have to make your money somewhere, or its not worth the endeavor.

Comment: Part costs have very little to do with electronics retail costs, especially for quantities below a few hundred thousand. And India has a special case of trying to prevent gender-selective abortion.

Comment: There may be ultrasound machines approved only for animal use that escape regulatory restrictions.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If it has to be "approved" then it is not unrestricted is it? I gave an example of a currently sold, brand new design, veterinary ultrasound above that uses a CRT displays. CRT displays were considered obsolete over 15 years ago.

Comment: @TylerDurden There are other countries.. probably in some countries no approvals are necessary for veterinary use, but this isn't my field. I recall some Asian units being sold which lacked FDA of any kind.. and it doesn't look like the FDA does much proactively [anyway](http://www.fda.gov/AnimalVeterinary/ResourcesforYou/ucm047117.htm)